# 404 ECS Fargate with Traefik

Tags: traefik, aws-fargate

I am getting 404 for Traefik with fargate. Trying Traefik with simple http configuration , my Traefik dashboard is working fine. My backend is simple java spring boot project is also running fine. Whenever I am trying to call my backend with Traefik , there is a 404

TRAEFIK ecs Task definition

```
[
    {
        "name": "gateway",
        "image": "traefik:latest",
        "essential": true,
        "command": [
            "--api"
        ],
        "essential": true,
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "hostPort": 8080,
                "containerPort": 8080
            },
            {
                "hostPort": 443,
                "containerPort": 443
            },
            {
                "hostPort": 4443,
                "containerPort": 4443
            }
        ],
        "dockerLabels": {
            "traefik.enable": "true",
            "traefik.backend": "traefik"
        },
        "logConfiguration": {
            "logDriver": "awslogs",
            "options": {
                "awslogs-group": "/ecs/traefik",
                "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
                "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
            }
        },
        "environment": [
            {
                "name": "AWS_REGION",
                "value": "eu-central-1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The TOML file

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
logLevel = "DEBUG" #DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, PANIC


[accessLog]
    format = "json"

    [accessLog.fields.headers]
      defaultMode = "drop"
      [accessLog.fields.headers.names]
        "Accept" = "keep"
        "Accept-Encoding" = "keep"
        "Accept-Language" = "keep"
        "Referer" = "keep"
        "User-Agent" = "keep"
        "Cache-Control" = "keep"
        "Content-Encoding" = "keep"
        "Content-Type" = "keep"
        "X-Trace-Id" = "keep"

[traefikLog]
    format = "json"

[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"

    [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"

[ecs]
clusters = ["traefik"]
watch = true
autoDiscoverClusters = true
refreshSeconds = 15
exposedByDefault = true
region = "eu-central-1"
```

My middleware task definition.

```
[
    {
        "name": "middleware",
        "image": "sample:latest",
        "essential": true,
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "hostPort": 8181,
                "containerPort": 8181
            }
        ],
        "logConfiguration": {
            "logDriver": "awslogs",
            "options": {
                "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
                "awslogs-group": "/ecs/middleware",
                "awslogs-stream-prefix": "middleware"
            }
        },
        "dockerLabels": {
            "traefik.frontend.rule": "PathPrefix:/sample",
            "traefik.frontend.entryPoints": "http"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: It is difficult to narrow down the issue without any error trace. Is your ECS task is in RUNNING state? Do you see any error in cloudwatch

Comment: @Haran Please have a look at the  github issue https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/4879